# RC filter location of the components

Tags: filter, passive-filter

does location of the circuit components actually matter in RC high/ low pass filters?
[image: High pass]

For example, is this also a high pass filter?

[image: Low pass]

And this low pass filter?

Comment: If Vout is on the right-hand side then the top filter is low-pass, bottom filter is high-pass, if you swap locations you get the opposite filter

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! I was confused because when I search high pass filter on google it only gives the bottom image with vout on the right side.

Comment: Yes, think of a capacitor as open-circuit at low-frequencies and short-circuit at high frequencies, for the bottom high-pass filter, when the frequency is low Vin is not connected to the output

Comment: oooh okay! 
Is capacitor passing high-frequency signals because charging/discharging time cant keep up with the period of high frequency signal??

Comment: For a series RC circuit, if the output is taken across C it's a low pass filter; if it's taken across R it's high pass. For a series RL circuit, if the output is taken across L it's a high pass filter; if it's taken across R, it's low pass.

Answer (score 3):

> does location of the circuit components actually matter in RC high/
>   low pass filters?

Yes it totally matters: -

[image]

At low frequencies (or DC) the capacitor blocks current flow to a large extent and therefore, in the high pass filter, there is very little signal voltage passed to the output. For the low pass filter, at low frequencies, very little signal current flows through the capacitor and therefore the output is not attenuated as much as at high-frequencies.

Comment: Okay thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your LPF (signal enters the R, passes thru to meet the C, with High Frequencies progressively shunted to GND) has a noisy, trashy GND, then you get trash out of the expected-to-be-clean-at-high-freqs LPF.

Thus yes, placement of components, and thus what "gnd" is picked from the large points on the GND daisychain, matters.

Answer (score 0):

I "Always" think in terms of impedance ratios for any circuit as a function of spectrum.

Zc(ω)=1/ωC. and the crossover frequency is when Zc=R

- and as others said testing for ω=0 and huge means C is open or closed as in a switch.
- and of course ω=2πf
- regarding noise , ground can often be noisy or radiated noise can be received by high impedance loops or by stray coupling L or V to nearby traces, so guard tracks with Gnd are advised and in some cases with large IO cables, a common mode choke.
- although we define "ground" as a 0V reference somewhere, it can shift due to conduction loss , impulse currents or lack of,shielding or lack of balanced impedance.